# How do you use kernel convolution to detect edges in an image using javascript?

Tags: javascript, gradient, convolution

Would someone be able to explain to me the math used in the example below?
https://mimicproject.com/code/0bd9c006-3bf1-dfa4-5fc1-84d5610584ec

I understand that it's using kernal convolution (of -1 0 1) but how does that lead to being able to detect the edges in the loaded image? Also, why do all the diagonal lines become visible when you view the x gradient and all the horizontal/vertical lines appear when you uncomment the line to show the y gradient? What does it mean by x and y gradient of the image?

Comment: I'm not sure that these kinds of questions are on-topic for Stack Overflow. Your questions may be more appropriate for the [Computer Graphics](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/) site, or *maybe* [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/). This might be off-topic because your question isn't about fixing or writing code at all, it's more about the theory/math behind processing images with convolution kernels and that theory isn't exclusive to Javascript or any programming language in particular.

Comment: Simply: images on computers are stored as a matrix of values indicating color (for RGB images) or lightness (for B/W).  An edge in an image is a place where there is a huge color or lightness gradient, i.e. going from black to white will be a change from ~0 to ~255 in a B/W image.  The kernel in your post just approximates the gradient by subtracting the value from one pixel to the left and right (x gradient) or one pixel up from the current pixel and one pixel down(y-gradient) of the current pixel.

Comment: @Romen I'll check those two links out - thank you for your comment!

Comment: @Jeff thank you - that makes so much more sense!